# Shouldn't we check for conditionally convergent in ratio test done to see the intervals of convergence in power series?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

(By A(n) I mean the power series)I understood that we use absolute value of A(n+1)/A(n) in ratio test because A(n) isn't neccessarily a positive value. We know when there is a limit of absolute value of A(n+1)/A(n), infinite series of A(n) converges because it is is absolutely convergent. But what about when series A(n) is conditionally convergent?

Comment: If the series $\sum A(n)$ is conditionally convergent, then either $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |A(n+1)/A(n)|$ does not exist or  $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |A(n+1)/A(n)|= 1$.

Comment: do you have an example of a conditionally convergent series and lim A(n+1)/A(n) does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test says that for a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = c$$
that if $c<1$ the series is absolutely convergent, and if $c>1$, then the series is divergent.

The test **cannot** show that a series is conditionally convergent. If a series is conditionally convergent, then either the limit above doesn't exist or $c=1$, and in both cases, we learn nothing from the ratio test.

Summary: If a series is conditionally convergent, then the ratio test will fail to tell you anything about that series.

Comment: than how can you say the series is divergent when c>1? It is not a absolute convergent but it might be conditionally convergent. Does divergent mean not absolutely convergent?

Comment: @ghooo A series $\sum a_n$ either diverges, converges conditionally, or converges absolutely. These are mutually exclusive options. Therefore, if a series is divergent it is not absolutely or conditionally convergent.